# MocksApex - behaviour verification

Tags: apex, failing-tests, design-patterns, test-data-isolation, apexmock

I am using the [ApexMocks framework](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks) and I am having the following error message:

> Class.MockTest.testBehavior: line 13, column 1 11:53:56.3
>   (10709808)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object

Anyone with experience with the [ApexMocks framework](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks) that can tell me why the test is failing?

**Class to test:**

```
public class fflib_MyList implements IList {
    List<String> myList;

    public fflib_MyList() {
        this(new List<String>());
    }

    private fflib_MyList(List<String> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public void add(String value) {
        myList.add(value);
    }

    public String get(Integer index) {
        return myList.get(index);
    }

    public void clear() {
        myList.clear();
    }

    public Boolean isEmpty() {
        return myList.isEmpty();
    }

    public interface IList {
        void add(String value);
        String get(Integer index);
        void clear();
        Boolean isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**ApexMocks test:**

```
@IsTest
private class MockTest {
    static testMethod void testBehavior() {
        // Given
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        fflib_MyList.IList mockList = (fflib_MyList.IList)mocks.mock(fflib_MyList.class);

        // When
        mockList.add('bob');

        // Then
        ((fflib_MyList.IList) mocks.verify(mockList)).add('bob');
        ((fflib_MyList.IList) mocks.verify(mockList, fflib_ApexMocks.NEVER)).clear();
    }
}
```

Source : [FinancialForce ApexMocks Framework](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen reports recently that `Test.createStub()` started returning null. Assuming the ApexMocks framework uses that method, which it almost certainly does, then that could explain the null pointer exceptions.

> Any1 having issues executing Test.createStub(Type,Object) today? Started seeing it return null an hour ago #askforce @SalesforceDevs

[Source](https://twitter.com/ImJohnMDaniel/status/892784946301079553)

Related Github Issue - [fflib_InvocationOnMock is failing](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks/issues/46)

Related Known Issue - [System.Test.CreateStub method returns NULL in Apex Tests](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001D19)

Comment: ApexMocks framework uses Stub API :(

Comment: On the plus side, from the Known Issue it sounds like the patch is already mostly deployed.